# Equivalence test for two samples of categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, equivalence, tost

Let's say I have two packets of sweets, which can either be red or black. The packets look different, but I think they were produced at the same factory. I decide that if the distributions of the colours of the sweets within the packets are adequately similar, they were probably made in the same place.

Packet A contains 20 red sweets and 10 black sweets. Packet B contains 10 red sweets and 5 black sweets, such that my two-dimensional contingency table is as follows:

| Packet | Red sweets | Black sweets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 10 |
| B | 10 | 5 |

A Chi-squared test on these data will give me a p-value of 1, which tells me that I cannot *reject* the null hypothesis (in this case, the hypothesis that the colour-distributions of the sweets differ).

But is there away to perform two one sided tests, thereby rejecting the respective hypotheses that there are 'too many' black sweets or 'too many' red sweets? Would such a test make sense for this purpose? Would it require an arbitrary acceptable difference, expressed as a number (or proportion) of sweets?

The samples in my example are quite small, but IRL I'm working with larger samples so please ignore that implied constraint (i.e. I'm not looking for an exact test).

Comment: I don't know if that is of any help but if you compute Fisher's exact test in R it will give you a 95% confidence interval for the odds ratio (as in `fisher.test(matrix(c(20,10,10,5),nrow=2)`). With your larger sample that should get smaller and smaller and you may decide at some point that it is small enough around `1` to be compelling for your purposes.

Comment: @Bernhard I think that might be the answer to this question, thank you. Would you considering submitting it as an answer?

Comment: Glad if it helps. I have added an answer with a pointer to some intricacies of that approach. Apparantly, 95% CI are a complicated matter. :-(

Answer (score 1):

There will probably be a number of different ways to approach the problem. The most simple (and easy to explain to non-statisticians) will probably be to compute a 95%-confidence interval for the odds ratio.
With a growing number ob observations that will close in and give a reasonable "feel" for how close the true odds ratio has been determined so one can decide, whether that is *"close enough to 1"* to be *"not of importance"*.

Note however, that computing sensible confidence intervals is not as easy as it seems. Whilst the R function `fisher.test` will print such a confidence interval, that is sometimes "not in line" with the $p$-value produced by the same function.

Should you work with R you should consider using the additional package `exact2x2` or at least read it's vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exact2x2/vignettes/exact2x2.pdf

Should you use some other statistics software package you might also want to glance over that same document to become aware of OR confidence intervals being a more complicated matter then most people(?) might think.

Comment: TOST is only equivalent to confidence intervals, if those confidence intervals are equal-tailed or "central" in Fay's terminology. Fisher's exact test is "minlike" and it's confidence interval would not correspond to TOST.